# How to read \r\n like a newline from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I store some data into MySQL. When someone enters data and enters a newline, this newline is stored as `\r\n` inside the database.

When I read this information from database the output is like that:

```
test\r\nxxx....
```

How can I read the `\r\n` like a newline? What I mean is the output should be like this:

```
test

xxxx
```

I store the input like that:

```
$desc=strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['desc']));
```

I use `nl2br()` and `htmlentities()` and it didn't give me the result I want.

How can I solve this problem??!!

Comment: What result does it give you? That info might be useful for us to debug this

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is the result i put it before test\r\nxxx....

Comment: Technically a single `\r\n` should never result in the output you want - you're expecting a double line break from a single (Windows) line terminator by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nl2br()` with the optional parameter set to `false`. [See the docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#example-5458)

```
echo nl2br("test\r\nxxx....", false); //Output: test<br/>xxx....
```

If you really want to get rid of the `\r`, then you need to remove it.

```
$tempArr = array();
foreach(explode("\n", "test\r\nxxx....") as $line)
{
    $tempArr[] = trim($line);  // removes all linebreaks and whitespaces, even \r
}
$text = implode("\n", $tempArr);
echo nl2br($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in that problem, where reading multiple lines from the database returns the `\r\n` encoded as such instead of the actual Ctrl-M and Ctrl-J characters.

What I've done is replace those characters with the `str_replace()` function like so:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\\r", "\\n"), array("\r", "\n"), $str);
```

Notice the use of two backslash. The PHP compiler will transform `"\\r"` into `\r` (an actual backslash `\` and the letter `r`). In the second array, it shows what we want to replace that with: `"\r"`, with a single backslash, which transforms the `\r` sequence in the value `0x0D` (Ctrl-M).

The same happens with the `"\\n"` and `"\n"` for the value `0x0A` (Ctrl-J).

Now the output will be:

```
test
xxxx
```

Note that the sequence `"\r\n"` represents one newline, not two. The `"\r"` means go back to the beginning of the line. The `"\n"` means go to the next line (or go down one line), if at the bottom of the console, scroll one line up too. In a Linux terminal, the `"\n"` is sufficient. On many terminals, such as MS-DOS, without the `"\r"`, you would get:

```
test
    xxxx
```

Of course, that does not happen at all in a browser. Actually, to see newlines in a browser, you need one of the `<pre>` or `<textarea>` tags. Most browsers expected the `"\r\n"` sequence in a `<textarea>`, which is a really old **telnet** thing (i.e. to make your text work properly in 99% of the terminals out there).

---

**WARNING:** Note that applying such an `str_replace()` more than once can cause issues. In other words, your application probably wants to do that just after loading the data from the database and not worry about it anywhere else. Otherwise, you could end up trying to replace more than expected and possibly break the user's data.